Catch them if you can... but you can't. (aka can't click "Watch tag" and "Ignore tag" from tag popup)
While reading this possibly related bug, I decided to check other popup: the tag popup.
When hovering over a tag, the familiar popup does appear, however when going with the mouse away from the tag itself, the popup disappears, even if I go to the popup itself.
This makes it impossible to click the Ignore and Watch for tag, though the popup itself is still useful to show the tag except, and I can click the tag itself to reach its page where I can Ignore or Watch it.
Browser Chrome 123, under Windows 7.

Same with Safari on macOS 14.

Workaround: use keyboard focus to trigger the popup, and just ensure you never mouseout the tag.

everything works on touch screen as well as with usercard :)

Another workaround is to right click on the tag, and hope the menu that opens doesn't entirely block the buttons.

This one's on me. I gave a quick update in this answer.

Fair, so closed as duplicate even though a different symptom of the same bug. :)
